# Could someone explain how a python daemon can also function to communicate with a running instance of itself?

Tags: python, interface, ipc, daemon

I'd like to implement a Python module that functions as a daemon and as an interface to that daemon. For example, when I run:

> python daemon.py do_something

The `daemon` module should try to communicate to the daemon to `do_something`, and if it doesn't exist, start the daemon and then `do_something`.

**NOTE:** I'd prefer to utilise the [daemon](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143) package in Python 3.

Comment: The normal way to communicate with a daemon is by using signals (see the `signal` module in the standard library).  However, signals are not the answer if you need to pass data as well, so it really depends on what you need to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX-compliant systems it is possible to pass the process arbitrary data locally with unix domain sockets. You can create both client and server socket using [socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). Parsing command line options (for example, using optparse or argparse modules) you can decide whether the daemon should be started or client socket connection opened to pass the command.